# Is it safe to always use the align_val_t overload of operator new/delete?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I was trying to write a simple allocation function and I was wondering if this is considered good practice or even correct

```
template <typename T> T *alloc(size_t count)
{
    return static_cast<T *>(::operator new(
        sizeof(T) * count,
        static_cast<std::align_val_t>(alignof(T)))
    );
}

template <typename T> void free(T *ptr, size_t count)
{
    ::operator delete(
        data,
        sizeof(T) * count,
        static_cast<std::align_val_t>(alignof(T))
    );
}
```

Is it guaranteed that the `align_val_t` overloads can always be chosen instead of the overloads without `align_val_t` where the latter would be correct? Does this still hold true for the required behavior of user-replacements of these replaceable overloads?

(Assuming the multiplication on the size does not overflow.)

Comment: cppreference [says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) these overloads should be used for objects whose alignment requirement exceeds `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` and for instance gcc allocator implementation also [does it](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/ext/new_allocator.h#L114) only if the object alignment exceeds the default

Comment: Beware that your allocator does not begin or end the lifetime of a `T` objects, it just creates and destroys the underlying storage. It is misleading for them to operate on `T` pointers, since those pointers don't actually point to objects of those types.

Answer (score 5):

I see no reason why the examples given would fail to correctly allocate memory.  [[new.delete.single]](https://eel.is/c++draft/new.delete.single) and [[basic.std.dynamic.allocation]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic#allocation-3), which define the behaviour of this `new` operator overload do not mandate using it only for types which require it.

The preference for using the `std::align_val_t` overload if and only if the type requires an extended alignment is due to [[expr.new]/19](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#19):

> Overload resolution is performed on a function call created by assembling an argument list. The first argument is the amount of space requested, and has type `std​::​size_­t`. If the type of the allocated object has new-extended alignment, the next argument is the type's alignment, and has type `std​::​align_­val_­t`. If the *new-placement* syntax is used, the _initializer-clause_s in its *expression-list* are the succeeding arguments.

However, this passage is immediately followed by:

> If no matching function is found then
>
> - (19.1) if the allocated object type has new-extended alignment, the alignment argument is removed from the argument list;
> - (19.2) otherwise, an argument that is the type's alignment and has type `std​::​align_­val_­t` is added into the argument list immediately after the first argument;
>
> and then overload resolution is performed again.

which says the `new` operator ought to fall back to the other version if the preferred one is not available.  This implies the standard intends to support situations where only one of the overloads is available.  This mostly arises for classes that define their own `operator new` member ([[expr.new]/12](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#12)).

Your allocation function has some other problems, though.  Other than the already-noticed arithmetic overflow, it fails to invoke the constructor in the storage allocated, which means it does not return a pointer to fully-constructed objects; you will probably need to invoke the placement overload of `new` as well.  But that is beside the main point.